Origin of the name "Boof" in Teen Wolf?
In the 1985 version of Teen Wolf Scott's close friend is named "Boof" (though IMDB does refer to her as "Lisa 'Boof' Marconi").  Is the origin of that nickname given anywhere in the movie or in related media (a novelization)?

There was no official novelisation

Honestly, the film was very light for merchandise. There wasn't a comic or graphic novelisation. It spawned a sequel and a spin-off reboot, but no help there.

If I recall correctly, it only got promotion at all because Back to the Future made Fox a star

Even the movie poster referred to BttF; https://www.reddit.com/media?url=https%3A%2F%2Fi.redd.it%2F97m4jndoz7b11.jpg

This was the real nickname of the person on which the character is based. Teen Wolf  Writer Jeph Loeb attempted to ask a girl in his college out and she misheard him call her "Boof". The nickname stuck.

The short version is she was my college girlfriend. What happened was, I was at Columbia and we used to sit on the steps that go up to the library. And during the springtime, kids just sort of sit out there and eat, talk and watch the girls go by. I was sitting there and she walked by, this beautiful young blonde girl. I don't remember exactly what I said, but it was something like "do you want to have lunch sometime?", as she walked by because I'm a smoothie, at the age of 19. And she turned around and goes "Excuse me?" and I said "I'm sorry, I just want to know if you wanted to have lunch sometime". And she said, "Oh, I thought you called me Boof", and I said "I'm sorry, that's not even English. I don't even know what you're saying to me" and she goes "No, that's why I stopped, because why would anyone call anybody Boof?". I said "Well, I didn't, but now that I've met you, I'm Jeph and you must be Boof". And then it became one of those things where she would call me Jeph and I would call her that, and that's how it all started"
Tiktok

